# private tekton listen github not use webhook

Tags: tekton

I'm using tekton and github integration to build github code locally. I know that events can be pushed to tekton via the github webhook. But my tekton is inside a firewall network, and I'm not allowed to leak tekton's event listeners.

I'm looking to see if I can get github's repository events from polling within the private network or some other way available and then execute the task?